# Laravel - form models and array classes

Tags: forms, laravel, model-view-controller

I want to use a form model and also add classes to the form

```
{ Form::model($client, array('route' => array('client.update', $client->id))) }}


{{ Form::text('name', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

This throw an error as it expects a string

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

This make the field blank.

```
  {{ Form::text('name', '', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

Is it possible to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@LeBlaireau

We need to write the code in below manner:

```
  {{ Form::text('name', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

Hear if you keep **second** argument as **null** than laravel will fill value automatically.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Actually this does not work it leaves the value blank.

Comment: @LeBlaireau Form::text name field should be same as database field. it will manage accordingly by using null as second perameter.

Comment: I changed the the field from 'name' to 'client_name' - this works prefectly